# Bootstrap container position

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I want to put some space at the top of my page, I'm using in the page 2 divs with class "container".

I made `class="container position"`, then `.position { margin-top: 15px; }`, I've tried to put `15px!important`, `position: relative; top: 15px` but nothing happens, any ideas?

Comment: Do you show your code HTML and css too. For more try. why use padding..

Comment: try padding-top: 15px

Answer (score 0):

Unless there are dependencies in your code, this should work with Bootstrap:

```
.position { margin-top: 15px !important; }
```

You can wrap your content as well with a margin/padding

```
<div class="wrapper" style="padding-top:15px">
<div class="container">...</div>
</div>
```